# adding and incrementing minutes to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas and i want to index it by minutes and further increment it by 1 minute.I want only minutes in the dataframe index.For example,
I have about 400000 rows in my dataframe so the last row should have time = 400000 minutes

```
Weekly Sales
3200
4590
1290
5600
8900
```

i want the output to be somewhat like this:

```
time   `     Weekly Sales
00:01:00     `3200
00:02:00      4590
00:03:00      1290
00:04:00      5600
00:05:00      8900
```

Comment: Do you have a formula of how many pandas you have at a particular time period? I don't think you're want to log 40000 minutes in your code.

Comment: i need to convert the time series data which is non continuous to continuous.so i want to represent it by minutes

Comment: There are only 1440 minutes in a day so I don't think you can have 400k rows indexed by hour:minute:second